# What shows/episodes are related to the Crisis on Infinite Earths crossover?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014, arrow, supergirl-2015

It was announced at the end of the 2018 crossover that this year's annual crossover of the Arrowverse would be

> Crisis on Infinite Earths

This crossover will go beyond the usual habit of featuring the main shows of the arrowverse in a mostly self-contained story that spans over a few episodes (one per show) and will features cameos from other shows like

> Black Lightning, Smallville, the 90s Flash

Moreover, elements preparing for the Crisis has been disseminated in the arrowverse almost since its beginning, the main one being

> Flash disappearing in Crisis announced by the 2024 journal since the season 1 of the Flash.

Not everybody is watching every show of the arrowverse and it is hard to keep track of everything that relates to the Crisis.

**What shows and episodes relates to the arrowverse's Crisis on Infinite Earths**?

Note: obviously, part of this (but not everything) is "Future Work".

Comment: Note: I will start answering the question when I get more time later today. Also, since the Crisis has not been broadcast yet, I will put the answer as "community wiki"

Comment: I'd happy to hear about the downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Crisis on Infinite Earths event itself

- Supergirl Season 5 Episode 9
- Batwoman Season 1 Episode 9
- Black Lightning Season 3 Episode 9 (expected to be a minor scene)
- The Flash Season 6 Episode 9
- Arrow Season 8 Episode 8
- Legends of Tomorrow Season 5 Episode 1

### Appearances of the Monitor

- The Flash Season 5 Episode 9 (Elseworlds, Part 1)
- Arrow Season 7 Episode 9 (Elseworlds, Part 2)
- Supergirl Season 4 Episode 9 (Elseworlds, Part 3)
- Arrow Season 7 Episode 22
- Arrow Season 8 Episodes 1 - 7: Very focused on the Monitor.
- The Flash Season 6 Episodes 1 - 8: Not as focused on the Monitor as Arrow, but every episode so far has some mention.

### Appearances of Leviathan

It's not as clear that Leviathan will be featured in the crossover, but some of the symbols Leviathan uses look suspiciously similar to the ones near the Monitor's base on the Flash.

- Supergirl Season 4 Episode 22
- Supergirl Season 5 Episodes 1-8

### Arrowverse episodes spoiled by the above

Many of the scenes showing the Monitor and Leviathan are small scenes at the end of finales. That means that they generally spoil events for the previous season.

- Arrow Seasons 1-7. Each episode of Arrow Season 8 is an homage to one of the previous seasons.
- Supergirl Season 4.
- The Flash Season 5.

### Character backgrounds

The following provide feature characters that will appear in the crossover, but are unlikely to contribute to the main plot.

- The Flash Seasons 1-4
- Supergirl Seasons 1-3
- Batwoman Season 1 Episodes 1-8. These take place prior to Elseworlds.
- Legends of Tomorrow Seasons 1-3
- Black Lightning Seasons 1-2
- Black Lightning Season 3 Episodes 1-8

### Loosely related

- Constantine Season 1. The actor and the character are the same as *Legends of Tomorrow*, but besides a shared backstory none of the events of *Constantine* have been mentioned during his time as a season regular on *Legends*, so they are unlikely to matter to the crossover.
- Smallville Seasons 1-10. The actor for Clark on Smallville has been cast for the finale, and the CW is the current rights holder.
- Superman Returns (movie). Brandon Routh will play Superman during the crossover, but the CW probably does not have the rights to the specific events of the movie.

Comment: There are more now in loosely related section

Answer (score 0):

### **The main event**

According to the Wikia for the Arrowverse, *[Crisis on Infinite Earths](https://arrow.fandom.com/wiki/Crisis_on_Infinite_Earths)* (simply called thereafter *the Crisis*) is

> the upcoming sixth annual shared multiverse crossover event between Supergirl, the upcoming Batwoman, The Flash​​​​​, Arrow​​​​​, and DC's Legends of Tomorrow. The crossover will air over three nights in December 2019 and air the final two episodes on January 14, 2020.

The episodes will be aired in the order above (Supergirl first, Legends of Tomorrow last)

### **Preparation of the Crisis**

In chronological order,

1. As many fans guessed,

> the Crisis mentioned in the future journal in the Time Vault in *the Flash*

is the Crisis on Infinite Earths.

2. *The Crisis* has been announced during the events of the fifth crossover *Elseworlds* where

> the Monitor is introduced. At the end of the crossover, Green Arrow makes a deal with the Monitor to save the Flash and Supergirl.

3. The character introduced in *Elseworlds* appears in the after-credits at the end of the season 4 of *Supergirl* and the season *7* of *Arrow*.
4. Season 8 of *Arrow* is a lead-up to the events of *the Crisis*.
5. A significant part of the episodes of the season 5 of *the Flash* that precedes *the Crisis* deal with the event.

### **Other shows related to the crossover**

Through various leaks and announcements, many characters from current and past DC shows are known or suspected to appear during the crossover, either as cameos or as important characters:

1. Black Lightning
2. Constantine
3. The Flash from the 90s show
4. *Smallville* characters
5. Brandon Rough's Superman from *Superman Returns*